Hopping frogs on an infinitely long row of cells
There is a row of cells that is infinitely long in both directions.
The cells are numbered with integers $...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...$ from left to right.
Initially, all cells are empty. At each time step,

Each frog will independently jump either left by 1 cell or right by 2 cells with equal probability.
All frogs at cell 0 are removed.
One frog is placed at cell 0.

After a sufficiently long time, what is the expected number of frogs $p_n$ in cell $n$?

Source: The exact source is unknown. I got a similar puzzle of going upstairs/downstairs from a friend and re-phrased it into cells and frogs as I think it is clearer in this way.
What I tried:

Using recurrence $p_n=\frac12(p_{n-2}+p_{n+1})$ but the boundary condition $p_0=1$ is not sufficient.
Simulation shows $p_n\rightarrow0.854...$ for $n>0$ and $p_n\rightarrow0$ for $n<0$.
import numpy as np
n=10000
p=np.zeros(4*n)
o=2*n
for _ in range(n):
    p[2:-1]=(p[:-3]+p[3:])/2
    p[o]=1
print(p[o-1000],p[o+1000]) # 1.0288682133996791e-209 0.8541019662496823




Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

@Jafe thanks, I've added attribution.

Your recurrence is more suitable to compute the expected number of frogs in a cell, not the probability to find one.  Do you want the probability to find one or the expected number of frogs?

@FlorianF thanks for the correction. I've changed the question to the expected number of frogs.

I'm writing an answer, can you put the line "p[o]=1" after the line "p[2:-1]=(p[:-3]+p[3:])/2" in your simulation so that it matches the question more closely ?

@Vincent thanks, I've updated the code : )

For what it's worth: 0.85410196... = (3sqrt(5)-5)/2 = 3phi-4

This feels more like a math problem than a puzzle but it has some nice twists.
Part 1: Let's solve the equation
$$p_n=\frac12(p_{n-2}+p_{n+1}) \\
p_{n+1} - 2p_n + p_{n-2} = 0 \\
p_{n+3} - 2p_{n+2} + p_n = 0$$
If we search solutions of the form $p_n = \lambda^n$ we get
$$\lambda^{n+3} - 2 \lambda^{n+2} + \lambda^n = 0\\
\lambda^3 - 2 \lambda^2 + 1 = 0\\
(\lambda - 1)(\lambda^2 - \lambda - 1) = 0$$
$$\lambda \in \{1, \varphi, \psi\}$$
where $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} = \frac{-1}{\varphi}$
We can verify that $p_n = 1$, $p_n = \varphi^n$ and $p_n = \psi^n$ for example verify the equation. All the solutions to the equation are actually of the form $$p_n = A + B\varphi^n + C\psi^n$$
But wait... none of these solutions correspond to the simulation! What is going wrong?
Part 2: An analogy
Let's consider the situation where the frogs only go one cell to the right.
If we try the same approach, we get the equation $p_n = p_{n-1}$ which has solutions of the form $p_n = A$. We could try using the "boundary condition" $p_0 = 1$ to get $A = 1$ and conjecture that we expect one frog on every cell if we wait long enough.
It is a stable solution, but not the limit solution reached from the initial state, because no frog can go to the left and end up on a negative cell.
The special rule on cell $0$ should not be used as a boundary condition, and instead can justify a different solution on the negative cells and on the positive cells:

For $n < 0$, the equation $p_n = p_{n-1}$ holds, and $p_n = A_1$.
For $n > 0$, the equation $p_n = p_{n-1}$ holds, and $p_n = A_2$.
For $n = 0$ we just have $p_0 = 1$, which gives us in turn $A_2 = 1$.
We need an extra argument like "no frog can reach a negative square" to declare that a limit solution should verify $A_1 = 0$
Even then it is not fully clear that the limit solution is reached (well in this simple case it is clear).

Part 3: A multi-part solution

For $n < 0$, the equation $p_n=\frac12(p_{n-2}+p_{n+1})$ holds, so $p_n = A_1 + B_1\varphi^n + C_1\psi^n$
For $n > 0$, the equation $p_n=\frac12(p_{n-2}+p_{n+1})$ holds, so $p_n = A_2 + B_2\varphi^n + C_2\psi^n$
We can prove by induction that the expected number of frogs in cell $n$ is lower than $1$ at all times (Thx @Nitrodon). This gives us $B_2 = 0$.
We can prove by induction that the expected number of frogs in cell $n$ is lower than $\varphi^n$ at all times (Thx @Nitrodon), in particular $\lim_{n \to -\infty} p_n = 0$. This gives us $B_1 = 0$ and $A_1 = 0$
We have $p_0 = 1$ so this gives us $C_1 = 1$
We have $p_{-1} = \varphi^{-1}$ and $p_0 = 1$ so this gives us $C_2 = \frac{1}{\varphi^4}$ and $A_2 = 1 - \frac{1}{\varphi^4}$

In the end, if we wait long enough, we expect $p_n = \varphi^n$ for $n \leq 0$ and $p_n = 1-\frac{1}{\varphi^4} + \frac{1}{\varphi^4} \frac{-1}{\varphi^n}$ for $n \geq 0$, which matches the simulation.

The expected number of frogs in any cell at any time is at most 1.  This is true in the initial state (with no frogs), and maintained by the recurrence.  Hence, if the expectation has a limit, that limit is at most 1 (and hence bounded).

thx @Nitrodon! Do you have an argument for the limit towards -infinity being 0 ?

I didn't at the time, but now I see that the same argument holds for φ^-n times the number of frogs in cell n.

Oh nice one, I'll add that as p_n is lower than 1 and also lower than φ^n

Why does $p_0$ also satisfy the equation for $p_n$?

@JohnAo The recurrence for $n < 0$ involves $p_m$ for all $m \le 0$, so the parametric solution also works for all $m \le 0$.

@Nitrodon althrough the results are correct, I think the "more rigorous" way is to use $p_{-1}=\frac12(p_{-3}+p_0)$ to solve for $C_1$ and use $p_1=\frac12(p_{-1}+p_2)$ and $p_2=\frac12(p_0+p_3)$ to solve for $A_2,C_2$.
